# Очистка некоторых полей на всех формах

Tags: javascript, php, html

Суть такова. При заходе пользователя на сайт с utm-метками, метки записываются в каждую форму как скрытое поле(input hidden), сохраняются в сессию(чтобы при переходе на другую страницу не потерялись). Далее если пользователь отправляет форму, сессия очищается, но скрытые поля ведь на всех формах уже заполнены. Как их очистить, после отправления формы?

Answer (score 0):

Для наглядности работы сделал очистку формы через 2 секунды.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var field= document.getElementById('textField');
field.value = 'some text';
setTimeout(function() {
  form.reset();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="textField" value="">
</form>
```

А если нужно не всю форму, а только определенные поля. То нужно просто записывать в них пустую строку, как в примере с "some text"

Comment: функцию reset я знаю. Вопрос в другом - как очистить все формы разом, а не конкретную.

Comment: @BeatLionHeart а что мешает все формы так же получить в переменную и выполнить reset?

Comment: и проходить их циклом? ну такое.

Comment: Ну можно и без цикла, просто подряд. Вполне нормальное решение, совсем непонятно мне чем вас оно не устраивает.

Comment: Должна быть функция resetAllFormsWhereExactlyAndWhenExactlyIWant(). При чем она должна поддерживаться всеми браузерами.

Comment: Как бы привлекательно не выглядел синтаксис jquery, внутри он все равно выполняет обход коллекции. А самый дешёвый обход это цикл, где доступ к следующему элементу получают смещением на одну ячейку памяти.